# iOS - Share Image with pre-filled caption to WhatsApp

Tags: ios, share, whatsapp

I'm looking for a way to share an image with pre-filled caption (a URL).

I have googled for this and also checked the official WhatsApp documentation, but I can't find a way to do this. Some of the SO answers tell that this is not possible right now in iOS.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741858/ios-share-image-and-text-to-whatsapp) SO question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089069/how-can-i-share-image-text-captionurl-on-whatsapp-from-iphone) too.

In Android this seems to be possible. See the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26971952/2442021).

Is there a way to share an image with pre-filled caption in iOS like in Android?

PS: I don't want to use Open Graph tags for this.

Comment: i have same question too please help .